# How to make third tier menus open inline with the item?

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wss5A/72/

Specifically with regards to:

```
2-A-1

2-A-2

2-A-3
```

The (third tier menu) is created from the top on the left, I would like the first sub menu element to be in line with either `2-A-1, 2-A-2, 2-A-3`

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your stylesheet with the following:

```
#menu >li > ul > li {position:relative;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Wss5A/74/)